# Limit and offset (pagination) for rows with related data (with joins)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables `Alpha` and `Beta`. `Beta` belongs to `Alpha`.

```
create table Alpha
(
    id int auto_increment primary key
);

create table Beta
(
    id         int auto_increment primary key,
    alphaId    int null,
    orderValue int,
    constraint Alpha_ibfk_1 foreign key (alphaId) references Alpha (id)
);
```

Here are a few test records:

```
insert into Alpha (id) values (1);
insert into Alpha (id) values (2);
insert into Beta (id, alphaId, orderValue) values (1, 1, 23);
insert into Beta (id, alphaId, orderValue) values (2, 1, 43);
insert into Beta (id, alphaId, orderValue) values (3, 2, 73);
```

I want to create a pagination for them, that would make sense in terms of my application logic. So when I set `limit 2`, for example, I expect to get a list of two `Alpha` records and their related records, but in fact when I set `limit 2`:

```
    select *
from Alpha
      inner join Beta on Alpha.id = Beta.alphaId
order by Beta.orderValue
limit 2;
```

I am resulted with only one Alpha record and its related data:

[image: ![enter image description here]

**While I want to figure out a way for my `LIMIT` construct to only count unique occurrences of `Alpha` records and return me something like this:**

[image]

Is it possible to do it in MySQL in one query? Maybe different RDBMS? Or going with multiple queries is the only option?

=== EDIT

The reason for such requirements is that I want to create an API with paging that returns records of Alpha, and their related Beta records. The problem is that the way limit works does not make sense from the user's standpoint: `"Hey, I said I want 2 records of Alpha with its related data, not 1. What is that?"`

Comment: ...that's how `JOIN` works. What would be the expected result?

Comment: The *wanted* result is shown on image 2, the actual result is shown on image 1.

Comment: Are you sure `alphaId` should point to table `beta`?

Comment: `LIMIT`-ing without `ORDER`-ing rarely makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I have added ordering and fixed `references` problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your example:

- Your foreign key seems to be wrongly established.
- Limiting overwhelmingly requires an explicit order of the rows. Otherwise the result will be *unstable* and non-reproducible.

Anyway, having said that, you can place a limit on rows for table `Alpha` and then perform the join against table `Beta`.

For example:

```
select *
from (
  select * 
  from Alpha
  order by id
  limit 2 -- this limit only affects table Alpha
) x
join Beta b on b.alphaId = x.id
```

Comment: Sorry, I have added it to my question.